# Golang continous workflow with docker

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

What is the best and simple way to do continuous development with docker and golang . What i am concern about is compiling and running and building docker images again when i change some code in golang .

I am using docker container inside docker machine without swarm and building containers with docker compose . Pretty simple strategy . Everything works fine . Just cant figure out the way to compile , build and run changed golang code instantly in running docker container without rebuilding the container again with static binary .

Answer (score 0):

Using wercker for local development will save you from rebuilding the container entirely on your machine. You can use `wercker dev` with `internal watch` and set the value `reload:true`. You can check the docs here [Go wercker local development](http://devcenter.wercker.com/quickstarts/building/golang.html) and this blog post [Introducing local development with wercker](http://blog.wercker.com/2015/05/15/Introducing-local-development.html)